# Dynamically added items don't raise events.(ASP.NET ListBox)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is:

```
private void Add_Items()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 53; x++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Item" + x);
            ListBox1.DataValueField = "Value" + x;
        }

    }
```

None of these items raises SelectedIndexChanged event when clicked.
Please assist.

Comment: Every item must keep a different value

Comment: Can You post Design page code for ListBox1

Comment: Share your aspx code for ListBox1.

Comment: In which step of the page life cycle is your Add_Items method called? OnLoad? OnInit?

Comment: Add items by calling: ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Name" + x, "Value" + x));

Comment: I only dropped a ListBox and set its AutoPostBack to true. Then added a few items some manually and some using a loop. The ones I added manually work. I call the Add_Items() in the Page_Load

Comment: I have learned that the items work but to a certain number. My ListBox is in an ajax tabContainer and it seems to limit the number of my items. Any idea as to how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure autopostback is enabled, like in this examle:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listBoxLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="listBoxLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="True">

<asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>
```

Or to dynamically populate:

```
Protected void Button1_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Carbon", "C"));
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Oxygen", "O"));
}
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14atsyf5%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: How will I be able to add 1000 items?

Comment: Thanks but still they dont raise events

Comment: Make sure values are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very vague, and im going to make the assumption that your ListBox has not been linked up to a SelectedIndexChanged event in the correct way.

If you are dynamically creating the ListBox link it up as below:

```
    public void initialize()
    {
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.SelectedIndexChanged += lb_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void lb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Selected Index Changed Code Here
    }
```

If you have a view/form with the control on, simply make sure that the ListBox's event has been set or naturally it will not trigger.

***EDIT 1**
As noted in other answers your control is required to have PostBack set. You should also be checking the PostBack state of your page to ensure you are not redrawing your controls continuously, as this will keep resetting your Dynamically added controls.

Answer (score 0):

First.

The `ListBox1.DataValueField` should not be set to every item. This property sets the field on the data object (each row) to capture the value from. Here is the MSDN link for this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(v=vs.110).aspx.

Next, I am assuming you have all the front end code wired up something like.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

This has the selected changed event wired up. However for this control to actually `Post` the data back you need to provide one more attribute. Add

`AutoPostBack="true"`

To your control as.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

This starts the magic. MSDN for AutoPostBack: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx